# Prove $\int_0^{1/2} \frac{dr}{|\log(r)|} < \infty$ using Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

I am stuck trying to prove

$$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{dr}{|\log(r)|} < \infty$$

using **Taylor expansions**

Since $$ \log(r) = \log(1+r-1)= r-1 +o(r-1) $$

$$ \int_0^{1/2} \frac{dr}{|\log(r)|}=\int_0^{1/2} \frac{dr}{|r-1 +o(r-1)|} $$

If this is correct, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: $log(r)$ is negative on the integration interval. So the integral is negative and $< \infty$.

Comment: @M.Wind Sorry I forgot the |.|

Comment: Note $1/log(0) = 0$, so the integrand does not diverge on the given interval. Thus convergence of the integral is guaranteed. To estimate the result you may expand around $r = 1/4$ or some other value.

Comment: Hint: compare the integrand to $\frac{1}{\ln2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0 < y < 1$ we have the Taylor expansion $- \log(1- y)= y + \frac{y^2}{2} + \ldots> y$.

Taking $r = 1-y$ it follows that $- \log r > 1-r$ and for $0 < r < 1/2$

$$\left|\frac{1}{\log r}\right| < \frac{1}{1-r}$$

Since $\int_0^{1/2} \frac{dr}{1-r} = \log 2$, the improper integral of $1/ \log r$ is convergent by the comparison test.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the |.|

Comment: I am not familiar with that Taylor expansion, could you elaborate on that? It seems to be an expansion at infinity

Comment: Also the basic inequality $\frac{x}{1-x} < -\log (1-x) < x$ for $0< x < 1$ comes in handy here.

Comment: @mathlover: Fixed typo. It should be $\log(1-y) = - y - y^2/2 - \ldots$ which is the Taylor series around $y=0$. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+series+log%281-y%29

Comment: Why is the inequality at the second line valid for 0<r<1/2 only?

Comment: @mathlover: It is valid for 0 < r < 1.  I wrote 1/2 because that is that is the upper limit of the integral we care about here. Note https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+1%2F%281-r%29+%2B+1%2F%5Clog%28r%29+from+0+to+1

Comment: Are you not following the steps here? If $-\log(1-y) = y + y^2/2 + y^3/3 + \ldots$ is the Taylor series converging when $0 < y < 1$, then because the terms on the RHS are positive it follows that $-\log(1-y) < y$ for all $0 < y < 1$.  Replacing y with $1-r$ we get the desired inequality to be valid for all $0 < r < 1$.

Comment: Every time I see this expansion I wonder why is the expansion valid for 0<y<1 and not for all y in the domain, ie $y<1$? Sometimes people only write the expansion not even saying what is the interval where it holds

Comment: @mathlover: The radius of convergence for the power series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k}$ is $1$. That is it converges  when $|y| < 1$.  It diverges when $y=1$ and converges whn $y= -1$ at the boundaries. The ratio test gives you that radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $log(x)$ is non-analytic in $x=0$. But $-1/log(x)$ is equal to zero in the limit of $x$ to $0$. So there are no problems on the interval given. Furthermore we can check that the derivative is positive everywhere, and therefore the function is monotonically increasing. So we can conclude that $-1/log(x) < 1/log(2)$. Hence the integral $< \infty$.

A reasonable estimate for the value of the integral can be found by replacing the integrand by its central value, $1/log(4)$. This way we get $I = 0.5/log(4)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the result $\int_0^1 r^x dx = \frac{r-1}{\log r}$

$$ \frac{1}{|\log r|}=\frac{1}{1-r}\int_0^1 r^x dx < \frac{1}{1-r}
$$
due to $r^x < 1$ over the integration range. Then, we get
$$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{dr}{|\log r|}
< \int_0^{1/2}\frac{dr}{1-r}<\infty
$$